# Using AFJSONRequestOperation On For Loop on iPhone SDK

Tags: objective-c, xcode, loops, afnetworking, afjsonrequestoperation

I have this code that I want to eager load using `AFJSONRequestOperation` before continuing with the for loop but somehow it doesn't work. The code below is inside my for loop. How can I prevent my loop from proceeding even if the request is not yet complete? This will help me place all the values got from a success request inside an array in the order I wanted it.

This is the code:

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[nowShowingTitleListArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"]];
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:theRequest
    success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON)
    {
        // Code when success
    }
    failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON)
    {
        NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }];

    [operation start];
```

Currently, I'm doing this to ensure that they'll be fetched and added to my array in order:

```
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[nowShowingTitleListArray objectAtIndex:i]]];
        NSError *error;
        NSDictionary *JSONDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                 options:kNilOptions
                                                                   error:&error];


        if (!JSONDict)
        {
            NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
        else
        {
            // Rest of code
        }
```

This will also help me minimize some of the crash issues I'm having with the request when the network connection suddenly drops out.

Comment: Your first code is asynchronous, which basically means all those requests are firing virtually at the same time. Second code is synchronous hence taking such a long time. Please look into `NSOperationQueue`s, and how to use them with network requests. You can create a dependency chain, while using asynchronous requests.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are you fetching your data from the same URL twice? 
Once using AFJSONRequestOperation and then dataWithContentsOfURL: 
Are you doing this in the same for loop?

You already have your JSON object in success block

```
success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON)
 {
    // Code when success
    // write success code here
 }
```

you can call AFJSONRequestOperation in loop for multiple network requests.

Comment: Nope. Those are different codes. The one above is what I wanted but messes up with the arrangement of items in my array while the one below is the one that works but is slower and can't handle errors properly.